# How to reinstall Powershell on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Using Windows 10 Pro Version 1909 (Build 18363.476), when I try to run in Powershell (Administrator):
`Get-Module -ListAvailable -All`

I get an access denied to location `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\BitLocker\BitLocker.psm1"` error, so it looks like my PowerShell installation is corrupt.

How can I repair/reinstall it?

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 cannot be "reinstalled" on Windows 10.  There is no way to reinstall or uninstall PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10.  [Releated: Command Prompt: access denied when run PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115313/command-prompt-access-denied-when-run-powershell)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact build of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: Have you tried running as Administrator?

Comment: @harrymc yes, as I've written in the question

Comment: Are you running `Windows 10 Home` or `Windows 10 Professional`?

Comment: Why do you think powershell is the issue rather than authority to access the *bitlocker.psm1* file?  It would help if you edited in the **full** results of `Get-Module -ListAvailable -All` rather than a partial result (although I tried to edit in what you gave).  You shouldn't try to guess an answer in your question - just describe the error.

Comment: @Ramhound Where are you getting Powershell 5.1 from? =]  @xnor that seems more like an ACL issue than a corrupted Powershell binary... you can verify though by running `DISM` and `SFC` in the sequence listed: `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` _(requires an internet connection)_ > `sfc /scannow`.  If `/restorehealth` fails, re-run after: `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`.  Please also update your question to include the output of the following; `cmd /c icacls %WinDir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\BitLocker\BitLocker.psm1`

Comment: @JW0914 - **Because I know the version of the powershell.exe executable is the same version as that of Windows kernel.**  Since I also know every version of Windows 8+ include PowerShell 5.1, I know that based on that fact, it cannot possible be any other version of PowerShell.  Which means the version of PowerShell the author is attempting to use is PowerShell 5.1.  **Why are so many people pushing back on the statements about .NET Framework and PowerShell 5.1?**

Comment: @Ramhound I just thought you made a typo, that's all =]  I wasn't aware of all of that though, so thanks! =]

Comment: Do you have 'System Restore Points' configured? If so, are you saying you tried to roll back and that did not work for you?

Comment: I tried both `dism` and `sfc` before and it didn't help. Is it possible that it doesn't include `" WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules"`?

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell is an integral part of Windows 10 and cannot be uninstalled.

What can be done is:

- [Download .NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework)
  and re-install the latest version.
  (Note: Reinstalling .Net is inconsistent. Windows will not agree
  to reinstall a version over itself, only over an older version.
  In some cases there will be an option to uninstall the latest .Net version
  and return to to an earlier version, but not in most cases.)
- Reset all Windows components to a known state by an offline In-place Upgrade,
  by "upgrading" Windows to itself (or to the latest version).
  This is equivalent to a major Windows update so take the same precautions.
  See the article
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8 cannot be reinstalled on `Windows 10 version 1909`.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not yet on it. Why is that?

Comment: The version of .NET that is included with Windows 8+ cannot be reinstalled.  You can upgrade whatever version that might be, and then uninstall that version, but you would end up with the version that was originally installed.  Only .NET Framework 3.5 can be removed from Windows 8+

Comment: @Ramhound: .Net 4.8 in Programs and Features has an Uninstall option. I wonder if it will then revert to an earlier version so that 4.8 can be reinstalled, although I didn't try. Did you?

Comment: I know for a fact .NET Framework 4.8 cannot be uninstalled on 1903 and 1909.  If you are able to uninstall .NET Framework 4.8 it means you are not running one of those versions.

Comment: @harrymc This is an issue of semantics, but it depends on what version of Powershell you're referring.  You're obviously referring to Powershell v1.0 that comes pre-installed on all versions of Windows, at least back to 7, located in `%WinDir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell`; however, [Powershell 6](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) and onward can be installed and uninstalled.  While an issue of semantics, I thought it important to mention.

Comment: @JW0914 - It's not actually "PowerShell 1.0", I cannot explain the reason it's located in a folder that makes it appear that is the case, but you are correct, it is entirely different to that of PowerShell Core 6.x

Answer (score 2):

While there is no offical way to repair PowerShell in Windows 10, here is how I did it:

- I just downloaded a VM image of Windows 10,
- zipped `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`
- saved permissions of the v1.0 folder into a file using `icacls`
- extracted the zip on the machine with the broken powershell
- restored file permissions with `icacls`

Now it works again.

Comment: There is a way to repair all Windows OS system files, which I explain in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1503460/how-to-reinstall-powershell-on-windows-10#comment2271264_1503460) comment under your question.  Windows includes a backup of every system file contained within `%WinDir%` in the Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`).  The DISM command in the comment verifies the backups in WinSxS against known good copies on the Windows Update servers, replacing any with a hash mismatch.  SFC then compares all Windows system files in `%WinDir%` against the known good copies in WinSxS.

Answer (score 1):

As an attempt to repair, you can disable and re-enable Windows PowerShell.  See [this post on Microsoft's forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/reinstall-powershell/9012f88a-e154-4fa1-a556-763120508ce1).  (**Edit:** Per Ramhound's comments, note that this is (at best) unlikely to help.  This does not uninstall or entirely disable all versions of Windows PowerShell)

If that doesn't work, you can attempt to [repair/reset/resinstall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026528/windows-10-reset-or-reinstall) Windows.  Note that your files and installed software will be affected by these options.

However (since you just said "PowerShell" and not explicitly "Windows PowerShell"), depending on your situation, you may wish instead to abandon Windows PowerShell and switch to PowerShell Core.  (If so, you'll likely want to disable Windows Powershell)   This may be preferable to resinstalling/resetting Windows, and this is actually Microsoft's prescribed solution for those who want the newer versions of PowerShell available; see [this Microsoft docs page.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6)

Here [is Microsoft's page on installing PowerShell Core.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6)  Here is a [3rd party guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/126551-install-powershell-core-windows.html), written in 2019.

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 cannot be disabled, uninstalled, or repaired on Windows 10.

Comment: Windows PowerShell 2.0 is an optional Windows feature still integrated into Windows 10.  Per the explanation I linked, if you run optionalfeatures.exe you are able to disable/enable it.  You are correct that this is not identical to entirely disabling Powershell 5.1

If you have some particular information as to the specific error mentioned in the question, you should include that info in your answer.

Comment: Are you positive the version of PowerShell that could be removed can even be installed on Windows 8+?  Based on my personal experience I don't believe that to be the case.

Comment: Powershell 2.0 can be disabled.  I don't know if it can be removed.  To reach PowerShell 2.0 in a default Windows 10 setup, run "PowerShell.exe - version 2".  I do not know what elements are included in Powershell 2.0, or what effect (if any) it has on other co-existing versions of Powershell.

Comment: Based on the version of the executable in that location on my system, I can confirm the version of `PowerShell` the author is using, must be `PowerShell 5.1` which means it cannot be reinstalled.

Comment: **_"Repair/Reset/Reinstall"_ is the wrong advice, as there's no justification for it.**  Windows comes with two native binaries, `DISM` and `SFC`,  for repairing Windows via the OS system file backups, kept in `%WinDir%\WinSxS`, where `DISM` should always be run prior to SFC due to the latter being dependent on the data the former is verifying.  Commands, issued in sequence listed: `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` _(requires an internet connection)_ > `sfc /scannow`.  If `/restorehealth` fails, re-run after: `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`